# Remove two activities from stack onBackPressed?

Tags: android

I have 3 activities, A, B and C. A opens B and then C immediately afterwards, so I am unable to call finish(); on B before C is opened. I have tried flagging B with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY but it is still opening when back is pressed from C. So, I am wondering if it is possible to tell activity C to remove both the current and previous activity from the stack onBackPressed(). I don't want to just open C by overriding onBackPressed as that will ruin my backstack. Any ideas?

EDIT: I am NOT opening C from B. A is opening both of them, hence my inability to just finish() B.

EDIT2: this is the code opening the new activities. (B is StandardInfoActivity, C is AddGradeActivity). They are opened by clicking an item in a listview (two different lists). When I open C, the activity for the same item in the other list also opens B underneath.

```
//make listview items respond to clicks and open relevant activity
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // selected item
            String standard = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(SubjectActivity.this, StandardInfoActivity.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("standard", standard);
            i.putExtra("subject", subjectId);
            i.putExtra("subjectName", subject);
            i.putExtra("level", level);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    gradeView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent2, View view,
                                int position, long id2) {
            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent j = new Intent(SubjectActivity.this, AddGradeActivity.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            j.putExtra("subjectId", subjectId);
            j.putExtra("position", position);
            j.putExtra("level", level);
            j.putExtra("subject", subject);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So try starting the intent call from B to C as "startActivityForResult" and call finish in B's onActivityResult.

Comment: Try adding finish() after the B's intent

Comment: @SonuSanjeev I am not opening activity C from B. Activity A is opening both of them, with C on top.

Comment: Local broadcast manager is an option that you can try. Send a broadcast when you press back from C and receive it in B and call finish. See if it works without crash.

Comment: A opens B and then C immediately afterwards--> What does this mean? Can you show code?

Comment: @VirRajpurohit code added

Comment: @Roonil Check my answer posted.

Comment: hence my inability to just finish() B?are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 1):

clear FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK when you open new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

like this do from Activity A to start B also

Comment: that code will remove everything from the stack. I only want to remove B. Also, I am opening both B and C from A, not C from B.

Comment: that case use back-pressed and customized code based on your working flow.i think no more option here

Answer (score 1):

The following code will remove all the backstack of A and B activity just use the code wen you go start a activity

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, activityRedirectClass);

          i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

          startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follow by calling a static method in that activity:

In Activity B declare variable

```
 static ActivityB activityB;
```

In `onCreate` write:

```
 activityB = this;
```

then add below function

```
public static ActivityB getInstance(){
   return   activityb;
 }
```

Now as you want to finish it up from ActivityC

Do it as below in your `onbackPressed()`

In activity C, call the function `getInstance()`

```
ActivityB.getInstance().finish();
```

Comment: It looks promising but I'm having difficulty getting it working. ActivityB i swap with the name of my activity B right?

Comment: I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.creation.elfho.ncearesultstracker.StandardInfoActivity.finish()' on a null object reference

Comment: This is a very bad apprach to have a static reference of a activity. So the activity instance will never be able to go under garbage collector

Comment: @ViswanathKumarSandu It is one of the approach. There must be better approach available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onActivityResult` method in activity B and call activity C using `startActivityForResult` method. Once you receive the callback on B, you can finish it. This will do the needful

Ref : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: But I am starting both B and C from activity A